# Column of counts for time intervals

Tags: postgresql

I want to get a table that constructs a column that tracks how many times an id appears in a given week. If the id appears once it is given a 1, if it appears twice it is given a 2, but if it appears more than two times it is given a 0.

```
id  date 
a   2015-11-10
a   2015-11-25
a   2015-11-09
b   2015-11-10
b   2015-11-09
a   2015-11-05
b   2015-11-23
b   2015-11-28
b   2015-12-04
a   2015-11-10
b   2015-12-04
a   2015-12-07
a   2015-12-09
c   2015-11-30
a   2015-12-06
c   2015-10-31
c   2015-11-04
b   2015-12-01
a   2015-10-30
a   2015-12-14
```

the one week intervals are given as follows

```
1 -  2015-10-30  to  2015-11-05
2 -  2015-11-06  to  2015-11-12
3 -  2015-11-13  to  2015-11-19
4 -  2015-11-20  to  2015-11-26
5 -  2015-11-27  to  2015-12-03
6 -  2015-12-04  to  2015-12-10
7 -  2015-12-11  to  2015-12-17
```

The table should look like this.

```
id  interval  count
 a    1         2
 b    1         0
 c    1         2
 a    2         0
 b    2         2
 c    2         0
 a    3         0
 b    3         0
 c    3         0
 a    4         1
 b    4         1
 c    4         0
 a    5         0
 b    5         2
 c    5         1
 a    6         0
 b    6         2
 c    6         0
 a    7         1
 b    7         0
 c    7         0
```

The interval column doesn't have to be there, I simply added it for clarity.

I am new to sql and am unsure how to break the dates into intervals. The only thing I have is grouping by date and counting.

```
 Select id ,date, count (*) as frequency 
 from data_1 
 group by id, date  having  frequency <= 2;
```

Comment: Is the interval data in a table? Also consider showing some attempt that you made to solve the problem - SO isn't a code writing service you know :) The problem isn't very hard to solve.

Comment: Is the first interval supposed to be 6 days or is that a mistake? And it is just these weeks or do you need a more generic solution?

Comment: jpw, I put up some code. I usually post on the R board, so I'm not well versed in the protocols on the SQL boards. I'll do more background next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at just the data you provided, this does the trick:

```
SELECT v.id, 
       i.interval, 
       coalesce((CASE WHEN sub.cnt < 3 THEN sub.cnt ELSE 0 END), 0) AS count
FROM (VALUES('a'), ('b'), ('c')) v(id)
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 7) i(interval)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, ((date - '2015-10-30')/7 + 1)::int AS interval, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY 1, 2) sub USING (id, interval)
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

A few words of explanation:

- You have three `id` values which are here recreated with a [`VALUES` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM). If you have many more or don't know beforehand which id's to enumerate, you can always replace the `VALUES` clause with a sub-query.
- You provide a specific date range over 7 weeks. Since you might have weeks where a certain `id` is not present you need to generate a series of the `interval` values and `CROSS JOIN` that to the `id` values above. This yields the 21 rows you are looking for.
- Then you calculate the occurrences of `id`s in `intervals`. You can [subtract a `date` from another `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) which will give you the number of days in between. So subtract the date of the row from the earliest date, divide that by 7 to get the interval period, add 1 to make the `interval` 1-based and convert to integer. You can then convert counts of > 2 to 0 and `NULL` to 0 with a combination of [`CASE` and `coalesce()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html).
- The query outputs the `interval` too, otherwise you will have no clue what the data refers to. Optionally, you can turn this into a column which shows the date range of the interval.

### More flexible solution

If you have more `id`s and a larger date range, you can use the below version which first determines the distinct `id`s and the date range. Note that the `interval` is now 0-based to make calculations easier. Not that it matters much because instead of the interval number, the corresponding date range is displayed.

```
WITH mi AS (
  SELECT min(date) AS min, ((max(date) - min(date))/7)::int AS intv FROM my_table)
SELECT v.id, 
       to_char((mi.min + i.intv * 7)::timestamp, 'YYYY-mm-dd') || ' - ' || 
       to_char((mi.min + i.intv * 7 + 6)::timestamp, 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS period, 
       coalesce((CASE WHEN sub.cnt < 3 THEN sub.cnt ELSE 0 END), 0) AS count
FROM mi,
     (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM my_table) v
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(0, mi.intv) i(intv)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id, ((date - mi.min)/7)::int AS intv, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY 1, 2) sub USING (id, intv)
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a834f/15) with both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table of all users, this will do the trick.

```
select 
    users.id,
    interval_table.id,
    CASE
        WHEN count(log_table.user_id)>2 THEN 0
        ELSE count(log_table.user_id)
    END
from users
cross join interval_table
left outer join log_table
    on users.id = log_table.user_id
   and log_table.event_date >= interval_table.start_interval
   and log_table.event_date < interval_table.stop_interval
group by users.id, interval_table.id
order by interval_table.id, users.id
```

Check it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1a822/21